# Page Rank in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, pagerank

I'm new to Python, and i'm trying to calculate Page Rank vector according to this equation in Python:
[image]

Where **Pi(k)** is Page-rank vector after k-Th iteration, **G** is the Google matrix, **H** is Hyperlink matrix, **a** is a dangling node vector, **alpha** = 0.85 and **e** is vector of ones.

The calculation with **G** takes a lot of time, while using the Hyperlink matrix **H**, which is sparse matrix, should take significantly less time.

Here's my code:

```
for i in range(1, k_steps+1):
  for j in range(0, len(dictionary_urls)):
    for k in range(0, len(dictionary_urls)):
        if matrix_H[k][j] != 0:
            matrix_pi_k[i][j] += matrix_pi_k[i-1][k] * float(matrix_H[k][j])
        alpha_pi_k_a += matrix_pi_k[i-1][k]*float(vector_a[k])

    alpha_pi_k_a = alpha_pi_k_a * float(alpha)
    alpha_pi_k_a = alpha_pi_k_a + float((1- alpha))
    alpha_pi_k_a = alpha_pi_k_a / float(len(dictionary_urls))
    matrix_pi_k[i][j] = matrix_pi_k[i][j] * float(alpha)

    matrix_pi_k[i][j] = matrix_pi_k[i][j] + float(alpha_pi_k_a)
    alpha_pi_k_a = 0
```

k_steps is the number of iteration needed.

dictionary_links contains all the URLs.

After code execution, matrix_pi_k should have all the Pi vector's

I calculated all the variables that needed. I got a run time using **H** matrix is almost equal to run time using **G** matrix, although, in theory it should be different.

Why? And what should I change to reduce the run time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're multiplying a sparse matrix by a dense vector using the same-old dense matrix-vector multiplication algorithm. You won't see any speedups that way.

Suppose you have an `nxn` matrix `A` (dense or sparse) and an `n`-vector `x`. To compute `y = Ax`, we can write:

```
y = [0]*n
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        y[i] += A[i,j]*x[j]
```

This works whether the matrix `A` is dense or sparse. Suppose, though, that `A` is sparse. We still loop over *all* columns of `A` to compute a single entry of `y`, even though most of the entries will be zero. So the outer loop goes through `n` iterations, and the inner loop also goes through `n` iterations.

If we *know* which entries of `A` are nonzero, we can do much better. Suppose we have a list of all of the nonzero entries of row `i`, call it `nonzero[i]`. Then we can replace the inner loop with iteration over this list:

```
y = [0]*n
for i in range(n):
    for j in nonzero[i]:
        y[i] += A[i,j]*x[j]
```

So while our outer loop does `n` iterations, the inner loop only does as many iterations as there are nonzero entries.

This is where the speedup comes with sparse matrix-vector multiplication.

## Use `numpy`!

But you have another problem: you're trying to do matrix multiplication with pure Python, which (due to type-checking, non-contiguous data structures, etc.) is *slow*. The solution is to use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org), which provides fast algorithms and data structures. Then you can use [`scipy`'s sparse matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html), as they implement fast sparse matrix-vector multiplication for you.

## Experiment

We can show all of this with a quick experiment. First we'll generate a `10,000 x 10,000` dense matrix `A`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n = 10000
>>> A = np.random.sample((n,n))
```

Then we'll make a sparse matrix `B` by thresholding `A`. `B` is the same size as `A`, but only 10% of its entries are nonzero:

```
>>> B = np.where(A < .1, A, 0).astype(float)
```

Now we'll make a dense vector to multiply `A` and `B` with:

```
>>> x = np.random.sample(n)
>>> %timeit A.dot(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 46.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit B.dot(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 43.7 ms per loop
```

It takes the same amount of time to compute `Ax` as it does to compute `Bx`, even though `B` is "sparse". Of course, it isn't *really* sparse: it's stored as a dense matrix with a lot of zero entries. Let's make it sparse:

```
>>> sparse_B = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(B)
>>> 100 loops, best of 3: 12 ms per loop
```

There's our speedup! Now, just for fun, what if we store `A` as a sparse matrix, even though it's really dense?

```
>>> sparse_A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
>>> %timeit sparse_A.dot(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 112 ms per loop
```

Ouch! But this is to be expected, as storing `A` as a sparse matrix will incur some overhead during the multiplication.

Comment: Okay, but the problem is even when I know which entries is zero, I should do the second part of the calculation, which affect every iteration.
by second part I mean the multiplication of Pi vector by vector a and add the result to Pi vector. So i can't skip the iteration even at entry with zero

Comment: @RomanYanovitski That's fine, since you don't need to compute `pi*H` and `pi*a` at the same time. You should really be using `numpy`, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your formula, calculation of matrix H doesn't look faster than for matrix G.

**Explanation:**

You might want to take a look at an [introduction to Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

The right-most part (after the `+`) in the formula only consists in a simple calculation without loops, and its Big O notation is just `O(1)`. Which means, it does not depend on the number of urls you are taking into account.

Whereas calculations both for H and G seem to be at least `O(n^2)` (`n` being the number of urls).

**Edit:**

In the deep nested part of your code, you have two instructions, one of them being conditioned upon whether `matrix_H[k][j]` is 0 or not. Still, if it is 0, which will be the case most of the time if H is a sparse matrix, the second instruction will be executed however. Plus, you enter the loop anyway.

That still gives you a complexity of `O(n^2)`, thus parsing H is not (much) faster than parsing G.

Comment: According to what I have read, multiplication of vectors that done on sparse matrix takes significantly less time than multiplication on dense matrix. G is a dense matrix, while H is sparse. This should influence on the run time.

Comment: @RomanYanovitski just edited my answer to take your comment into account

Comment: That's exactly what i'm asking:). My code, apparently, isn't efficient, and takes much more time than it should. And I don't see how can I improve it, to reduce it's run time.

Comment: @RomanYanovitski ok, I was answering to the "why" part of your question. Now for the "how", it's another story :) let me see if I can get to something worthy.